# How are GNU documents in PDF formats created?

Tags: pdf, gnu, documentation

Some GNU software doesn't offer PDF files for its manual, e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html

Some does, and their PDF files have bookmarks/outlines, e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/

1. How are those GNU documents in PDF format created?
2. How can I create PDF files in the same or similar style for GNU
   software which doesn't offer PDF manual?

   For example, is it possible and good idea to create from texinfo
   source files? I tried `texi2pdf find.texi` but it doesn't work:

   ```
   $  texi2pdf find.texi 
   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdfetex)
    restricted \write18 enabled.
   entering extended mode
   (./find.texi (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/texinfo/texinfo.tex
   Loading texinfo [version 2014-12-03.16]: pdf, fonts, markup, glyphs,
   page headings, tables, conditionals, indexing, sectioning, toc, environments,
   defuns, macros, cross references, insertions,
   (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/epsf/epsf.tex
   This is `epsf.tex' v2.7.4 <14 February 2011>
   ) localization, formatting, and turning on texinfo input format.) (./find.aux)
   (./version.texi)
   ./find.texi:10: I can't find file `../locate/dblocation.texi'.
   @temp ->@input ../locate/dblocation.texi

   @includezzz ...and @input #1 }@expandafter }@temp
                                                     @popthisfilestack
   l.10 @include ../locate/dblocation.texi

   (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
   ```

Comment: I have not got the time for it right now, but: 1. Download source. 2. `./configure` 3. Look at `Makefile` in `doc`.  (Source download on Debian + der. `apt-get source bash`)

Comment: @Sukminder: Thanks. I tried your way. As the Makefile suggests, I run `make pdf`, from its stdout output, I saw that it runs  `texi2dvi --pdf --batch  --build-dir=find.t2p -o find.pdf find.texi`, so it reports the same error `./find.texi:10: I can't find file 'dblocation.texi'.`

Answer (score 1):

The PDF files are created in a variety of ways, sometimes converted from a DVI file by `dvipdfm`, sometimes converted from a PostScript file by `gs`...

For `findutils`, the provided build scripts are incorrect; here's the short version (for 4.6.0), after extracting the source code:

```
cd findutils-4.6.0
./configure
make -C lib
make -C gl/lib
make -C locate
```

(this creates `dblocation.texi`)

```
cd doc
texi2pdf -I ../locate find.texi
```

Generally speaking, it should always be possible to produce a PDF with links etc. from a `.info` file; but you might need to figure out how to produce all the required input files...

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how to know what input files are required, how to specify them to `texi2pdf`, and how to produce them if they do not exist?

Comment: To know what input files are required, you can run `texi2pdf` as you did and interpret the errors; then you need to find the missing files in the source tree, or look for their names in Makefiles. If you find them in a Makefile, run `make` in the corresponding folder (as I did using `-C` above), and fix any errors that crop up there (there's no general rule here). Finally to tell `texi2pdf` where to find them, add `-I` options as I did above to point it to `../locate` (where `dblocation.texi` is created).

Comment: "the provided build scripts are incorrect"? How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `texi2pdf(1)` (part of `texinfo-tex` here on Fedora) which does the deed from the `.texi` (TeXinfo) sources for the GNU `info` documentation.

The `.texi` files themselves are normally bundled in the source packages. You should be able to build the PDF documentation with the standard `./configure; make` dance, or perhaps `make doc`.

Note that some commands are bundled, `find` in `findutils`, and a lot of standard Unix commands in `coreutils`. Their documentation is part of a larger document, and probably can't be built standalone.